# Batch script - invalid syntax in FOR /F

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script which is supposed to parse a file with file names and timestamps in it.

```
:MAIN

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F "tokens=1,2,4 skip=7" %%A in (C:\list_of_psa_files.txt) DO
@echo %%A %%B %%C 

exit
```

The file C:\list_of_psa_files.txt has the following data in it

```
Volume in drive C is Windows XP 6.6
Volume Serial Number is AC12-84AA

Directory of C:\Test

10/05/2011 03:17 PM <DIR> .
10/05/2011 03:17 PM <DIR> ..
10/05/2011 01:21 PM 4,393 1-16332-1008261.psa
10/05/2011 01:21 PM 4,863 1-16332-1011698.psa
10/05/2011 01:21 PM 4,793 1-16332-1023151.psa
10/05/2011 01:21 PM 4,916 1-16332-1035695.psa
10/05/2011 01:21 PM 4,524 1-16332-1037029.psa
10/05/2011 01:21 PM 4,235 1-16332-1049340.psa
10/05/2011 01:21 PM 3,135 1-16332-1049926.psa
10/05/2011 01:21 PM 4,657 1-16332-1054756.psa
```

However, when I am running my script it is failing with a message invalid syntax. Can somebody please help me figure out where am I going wrong.

All I am trying to do is to get the date, time and the filename without the extension written to a new file from my old file.

Thanks for your time - appreciate it.

Sanders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *really* have your `echo` on a separate line (and it's not an artefact of the editing process), you can't do that. You will need to use either one line or:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,4 skip=7" %%A in (C:\list_of_psa_files.txt) DO (
    @echo %%A %%B %%C 
)
```

When I create the file and script you show, I get:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

When I then change it to my suggested variant, it outputs:

```
10/05/2011 01:21 4,393
10/05/2011 01:21 4,863
10/05/2011 01:21 4,793
10/05/2011 01:21 4,916
10/05/2011 01:21 4,524
10/05/2011 01:21 4,235
10/05/2011 01:21 3,135
10/05/2011 01:21 4,657
```

as expected. The same output appears when you do it on one line with:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,4 skip=7" %%A in (C:\list_of_psa_files.txt) DO @echo %%A %%B %%C
```

Comment: But then when I tried redirecting my output to another file, I just get one line of it. Like this - 10/05/2011 01:10 24,971    And the code for that is SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
:MAIN


FOR /F "tokens=1,2,4 skip=5"  %%A in (C:\list_of_psa_files.txt) DO ( @echo %%A %%B %%C  > C:\list_of_file_ts.txt )

exit

Comment: That's a _different_ question, @user982201, but I'll help you out anyway. You're doing the `blah blah >out.txt` for every iteration. In other words, each iteration _overwrites_ the file meaning you'll only get the last one. Do a `del out.txt` _before_ the `for` statement to empty it, then use `>>` instead of `>` so that each iteration _appends_ its data rather than overwriting it.

Comment: +1 If it's a single command that's not long, for the sake of saving digital trees, use one line. No need to use 3 lines of code when reading 1 line is equally productive in this case.

Comment: @user982201, don't forget to press the tick mark next to the answer that answered your question.